# gzip compression with nginx - Not being reported correctly in tests?

Tags: nginx, gzip, compression

nginx 1.4.2

Google Pagespeed Insights (web version) is reporting that I should compress a number of .js files on my site.

I've checked the mime.types config file and it includes the default application/x-javascript           js; directive.  I've also verified through Firefox that the pages Insights reports as needing compression do present as application/x-javascript, yet according to Insights they don't appear to be being gzip'd.Also

I've also confirmed that nginx.conf has the following and that gzip is set to "on":

```
gzip_types  font/ttf font/opentype application/vnd.ms-fontobject image/svg+xml text/plain text/css image/png image/gif image/jpeg  text/xml application/xml application/x-javascript application/x ml+rss text/javascript;
```

Is there anything else I can try?  gzip appears to be working fine on images and other assets it's just .js files that Insights isn't happy with.

Thanks,

Steve

Comment: Can you post the related nginx config of that particular vhost?

Answer (score 1):

Check, if gzip options are enabled per virtual host. To enable css and js compression `gzip_types      application/x-javascript text/css text/plain;` is enough. Also, make sure your files match `gzip_min_length` option.